# How to convert anonymous list in list of RoleViewModel?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, generic-list

In my action method I am running the following query which returns a list :

```
var list = db.WorkRoles.
                Join(db.WorkRolesUsersDetails,
                o => o.WorkRoleId, od => od.WorkRoleId,
                (o, od) => new
                {
                    WorkRoleId = o.WorkRoleId,
                    RoleName = o.RoleName,
                    RoleDescription = o.RoleDescription,
                    CompanyId = o.CompanyId,
                    WRUDId = od.WRUDId,
                    UserDetailsId = od.UserDetailsId,
                    FocusStart = od.FocusStart,
                    FocusEnd = od.FocusEnd
                }).ToList();
```

I have a viemodel in the same format looking like this :

```
public class RoleViewModel
{
    public RoleViewModel(int workRoleId, string roleName, string roleDescription, int companyId, int wRUDId, string userDetailsId, DateTime focusStart, DateTime focusEnd)
    {
        WorkRoleId = workRoleId;
        RoleName = roleName;
        RoleDescription = roleDescription;
        CompanyId = companyId;
        WRUDId = wRUDId;
        UserDetailsId = userDetailsId;
        FocusStart = focusStart;
        FocusEnd = focusEnd;
    }
    int WorkRoleId { get; set; }
    string RoleName  { get; set; }
    string RoleDescription { get; set; }
    int CompanyId { get; set; }
    int WRUDId { get; set; }
    string UserDetailsId { get; set; }
    DateTime FocusStart { get; set; }
    DateTime FocusEnd { get; set; }
}
```

What is the best way to convert the result of my query to a list of my viewmodel?

Comment: Is there a reason you are making it a generic list in the first place? You should be able to select directly into a new object `=> new RoleViewModel() { property assignment }`

Comment: @JaredStroeb when i try that(suggested in one of the answers here) it gives me this exception : An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

Comment: Yes I have run into the parameterless constructor problem, but it should accept the generic constructor followed by property assignments. Is there an inner exception or more info in the NotSupportedException? Does the answer from @Michael throw an exception as well? (it might need another `.ToList()` at the end of his example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want your action method to be aware of View Model type than you can try the following things.

1. Use `Select` on the initial list and construct `RoleViewModel` for every item.
2. Use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) library that will do the job for you.

   `var list = db.WorkRoles.
                   Join(db.WorkRolesUsersDetails,
                   o => o.WorkRoleId, od => od.WorkRoleId,
                   (o, od) => new
                   {
                       WorkRoleId = o.WorkRoleId,
                       RoleName = o.RoleName,
                       RoleDescription = o.RoleDescription,
                       CompanyId = o.CompanyId,
                       WRUDId = od.WRUDId,
                       UserDetailsId = od.UserDetailsId,
                       FocusStart = od.FocusStart,
                       FocusEnd = od.FocusEnd
                   }).ToList()
                   .Select(item => new RoleViewModel(
                      item.WorkRoleId,
                       item.RoleName,
                       item.RoleDescription,
                       item.CompanyId,
                       item.WRUDId,
                       item.UserDetailsId,
                       item.FocusStart,
                       item.FocusEnd));`

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = db.WorkRoles.
            Join(db.WorkRolesUsersDetails,
            o => o.WorkRoleId, od => od.WorkRoleId,
            (o, od) => new RoleViewModel(
                o.WorkRoleId,
                o.RoleName,
                o.RoleDescription,
                o.CompanyId,
                od.WRUDId,
                od.UserDetailsId,
                od.FocusStart,
                od.FocusEnd
            )).ToList();
```

Comment: An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

Comment: Use `Select` after `ToList`. `ToList` call will materialize the objects